# Oauth Spring Security not unauthorized to microservice oauth, registerController

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am beginner to Spring. I've been with this problem for several days and I wouldn't know how to solve it.

I have two microservices:

1. Microservice authentication : This allows return a `JWT token` to user when it access to path: `/oauth/token`
2. Microservice Account user : This microservice will have a lot of functions but the problem is it:

The user must be register in platform and this microservice call to server oauth to save the new created user.

So, I create the controller to microservice Oauth:

```
 @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('server')")
    public UserDto createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        Usuario savedUser = new Usuario();
        try {
            savedUser = userService.create(this.toUsuario(userDto));
        } catch (ArendheException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toDto(savedUser);

    }
```

The WebSecurityConfigureAdapter is:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService usuarioService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


    }

}
```

As you can see, I write two `antMatchers`, the second to create a new user.

The problem is when I test it with *Postman* (path `localhost:8005/user` with data JSON parsed to POST method). The output is:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I dont understand it because I have a `permitAll` to `/user/** path`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you add the Authorization header to the request?